# How can a neural net recognize it is out of its training domain?

Tags: neural-networks, outliers, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

In a recent kaggle competition with a huge overfitting potential the winning team first searched for features on the training data and after the feature engineering used a Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test for comparing the distribution of the features on the training and validation set.

Features with a different distribution on the validation set were excluded. (https://www.kaggle.com/c/LANL-Earthquake-Prediction/discussion/94390#latest-632778)

My question is how it is possible to replicate this for a neural network and to realize that the feed forward features of a layer in the end of the network are different from the domain it was trained on?

Is there any research that is going into this direction?

Answer (score 0):

Why should it be different? You cannot determine whether a feature is in or out of your training domain unless you have an idea what that domain *is*.

If do you know, or at least can reasonably make an assumption about that ahead of time, you can throw some model comparison/goodness-of-fit metric at it.

A standard VAE is a nice case to examine, as it explicitly regularizes the latent space sizes to a `Gauss(0, 1)`. If your training encodings are well-behaved but your test encoding mean suddenly blows up to, say, `[6.34, 1]`, something's clearly amiss.

The big problem here is that you'd need to model the distributions of activations *within the model*, which suggests something more along the lines of a Hierarchical Bayes.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I will think about it. I would say is different in the sense that a KS Test becomes untraceable for e.g. segmentation tasks.